# Symfony2 store Doctrine result in csv file

Tags: php, symfony, csv, doctrine-orm

I am working with Symfony2 framework, I am fetching data from DB through Doctrine, now I want to save query result in CSV format.

my Doctrine query result array structure:

```
array('id' => '1', 'firstname' => 'Paul', 'surname' => 'White', 'email' => 'paul_white@gmail.com')
```

my code:

```
    public function dataToCSV($records)
{
    $cavPath = 'Test\TestBundle\Resources\reports\test2.csv';
    $csvh = fopen($cavPath, 'w');

    foreach ($records as $record)
    {
        fputcsv($csvh, $record);
    }

    fclose($csvh);
}
```

the $records param picked ups the query result.

The problem is i get no errors but at the same time i cannot see the csv file being stored in given path 'Test\TestBundle\Resources\reports\test2.csv'.

Maybe there is a stable Symfony bundle that can do all this for me...?

Comment: Try add the flush with `fflush($csvh);`  before the fclose statement

Comment: good phplibrary for manage csv are `goodby/csv` and `league/csv`

Comment: @Matteo thx for they replay unfortinally the first suggestion did not work, I am trying the goodby/csv library.

Comment: Hi @Tomazi good choice

Comment: I would say, revisit this:

    $cavPath = 'Test\TestBundle\Resources\reports\test2.csv';

better to pass a parameter with your kernel route or absolute path

Answer (score 0):

OK well I got a answer for my question so:

Because I am working unix system (Mac os) my slashes were the wrong way plus the SYmfony2 default directory is web so i had go back one directory back.

solution

```
..src/Test/TestBundle/Resources/reports/test2.csv
```